# How To Obtain the Smtp Server?

Tags: smtp, azure

I've gone through [this set up](http://www.dovetail.ie/blog/2015/azure-vm-smtp/#.V4IuYfkrLIV) for an Azure server VM and when I create a file with the below format and drop it into `C:\inetpub\mailroot\Pickup\` it sends without issue.

```
TO: to@email.com
FROM from@email.com
SUBJECT: Test
Test
```

However, I want to use PowerShell or .NET's email library.  I'm getting errors on the `smtp server` parameter when using the simple one line call:

```
Send-MailMessage
```

What I've tried for the `-smtpserver` parameter is:

1. `localhost`
2. The IP address of the machine
3. The syntax of smtp.DNSname.com based on the DNS name listed in the IIS configuration; example, `smtp.MyVirtualMachineDNSName.com`.

However, I get errors on all of these for the SMTP server.  I did validate the DNS name through the IIS 6.0 configuration manager.  So what am I missing to get a SMTP server set up?

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: For completeness' sake, here is the question on [so]: [How To Obtain the Smtp Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38291323/486504) That said, I absolutely agree with DavidPostill's comment above.

Comment: @GambleNerd Cannot find the server.